# IFrame Responsive issue

Tags: html, css, iframe

How to make the iframe in responsive with full width

```
iframe {position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100%; height:100%;}
iframe, object, embed {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

This is my code but not working

Note:

If we have used height in pixels(IFRAME Tag) then comes correctly in full width. But not working in responsive

what is the solution?

Comment: First of all, there is no "in responsive". 2nd, where is your HTML? 3rd, you might want to give us a fiddle.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. How does what you see differ from what you expect to see?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for. I assume that you are using YouTube so just paste in the embed link where the other link is.

**HTML**

```
<div class="videoWrapper">
    <!-- Copy & Pasted from YouTube -->
    <iframe width="560" height="349" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/n_dZNLr2cME?rel=0&hd=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.videoWrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 */
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}
.videoWrapper iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I used this guide: https://css-tricks.com/NetMag/FluidWidthVideo/Article-FluidWidthVideo.php

I used the same method for my own website and it works great. Hope this helps you out!

Comment: Hi dude its not working fine I am using the fixframe plugin